# Passing data to input tag in bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm working in a J2EE project and I had a problem that ruined my life :v I already worked with bootstrap and I already used bootstrap modal and passing data to modal, but this time, when I use the same code, it doesn't work.

PS: in the snippet it works, it means the code is right, but in my project it doesn't. what does it mean.

```js
$(".modal-link").click(function() {
  $("#descr").attr('value', $(this).attr('descr'));
  $($(this).attr('href')).modal('show');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class='modal small fade' id='myModal' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='myModalLabel' aria-hidden='true'>
  <div class='modal-dialog'>
    <div class='modal-content'>
      <div class='modal-header'>
        <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-hidden='true'>×</button>
        <h3 id='myModalLabel'>Detail</h3>
      </div>
      <div class='modal-body' id="Details">
        <input id="descr" name="descr" value="" />
      </div>
      <div class='modal-footer'>
        <button class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal' aria-hidden='true'>Fermer</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <c:forEach items='${liste}' var='p'>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <div class="media services-wrap wow fadeInDown">
        <div class="pull-left">

        </div>
        <div class="media-body">
          <h3 class="media-heading">${p.getMarque()}</h3>
          <p id="des">${p.getDescr()}</p>
        </div>
        <a href="#myModal" class="modal-link" var descr="${p.getDescr()}" role='button' data-toggle='modal'>
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open">View</i>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </c:forEach>
</div>
```

Comment: ${p.getDescr()} replace with  ${p.descr} and try it please. descr your private attribute. and ${p.marque}

Comment: @Gurkan Yesilyurt the problem in not there. ${p.getDescr()}  and  ${p.marque}  are showed without any problem. my problem is in the modal. I pass the value of ${p.getDescr()} in a variable called descr and I try to put its value to my input tag in the modal which its id is "descr" it can't be assigned!
I already worked with the same code, and there was no problem, I don't know what's wrong now!

Comment: It works in the snippet only once. Same goes for your server. It sets the value once, then it won't work anymore. When you open modal it's value is set correctly, try to change it's input's value and reopen it. The value won't change even though the `attr()` method is called again.

Comment: in the snippet it works only once, in my project it doesn't work at all

Comment: @Bashir You are still using incorrect method, did you change attr() to prop() and tried it again?

Comment: @Linek  yes I did change it! same problem

Comment: @Bashir The code you posted is working just fine after changing `attr()` to `prop()` so the problem is somewhere else. Either post more code or give us an url to your live website.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Never mind my post. You already figured out the issue is not with your javascript or mark up.

Your code seems to be working fine so the issue apparently is else where. 
I only took out the foreach loop and variables and hard coded the descriptions. The input inside the modal are populated with different description depending on link pressed. By the way you don't need to explicitly open the modal with .show().

```js
$(".modal-link").click(function() {

  $("#descr").attr("value", $(this).attr('descr'));
  //$($(this).attr('href')).modal('show');


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />



<div class='modal small fade' id='myModal' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='myModalLabel' aria-hidden='true'>
  <div class='modal-dialog'>
    <div class='modal-content'>
      <div class='modal-header'>
        <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-hidden='true'>×</button>
        <h3 id='myModalLabel'>Detail</h3>
      </div>
      <div class='modal-body' id="Details">
        <input id="descr" name="descr" value="" />
      </div>
      <div class='modal-footer'>
        <button class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal' aria-hidden='true'>Fermer</button>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="media services-wrap wow fadeInDown">
      <div class="pull-left">

      </div>
      <div class="media-body">

      </div>
      <a href="#myModal" class="modal-link" var descr="Description 1" role='button' data-toggle='modal'>
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open">View</i>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="media services-wrap wow fadeInDown">
      <div class="pull-left">

      </div>
      <div class="media-body">

      </div>
      <a href="#myModal" class="modal-link" var descr="Description 2" role='button' data-toggle='modal'>
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open">View</i>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I think I have an other problem, I still don't know what is it, because my code works fine in other projects, also when I run code snippet here it works fine, I added you answer (without foreach) and it still don't work while your code is correct.. I am lost !

Comment: Your snippet isn't working. Open modal, change it's input's content and reopen it. Input content will stop changing. `attr()` method is incorrectly used here.

Answer (score 0):

You are incorrectly using `attr()` method. Use `prop()`.

```
$(".modal-link").click(function() {
  $("#descr").prop('value', $(this).attr('descr'));
  $($(this).attr('href')).modal('show');
});
```

Read more on [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/). The most important part is:

> Nevertheless, the most important concept to remember about the checked
>   attribute is that it does not correspond to the checked property. The
>   attribute actually corresponds to the defaultChecked property and
>   should be used only to set the initial value of the checkbox. The
>   checked attribute value does not change with the state of the
>   checkbox, while the checked property does. Therefore, the
>   cross-browser-compatible way to determine if a checkbox is checked is
>   to use the property
>
> The same is true for other dynamic attributes, such as selected and value.

In other words `attr()` method only changes default value of the attribute (value in this case). If you change input `value` and try to use `attr()` method to change it, it won't work because default value != current value. To change current value you have to use [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) or [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) methods.